# Baking materials with alpha-blended textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency, baking

I'm currently trying to bake some low-poly assets for use in realtime applications.

I'm familiar with baking high-polygon meshes into low-polygon versions, but it would be helpful to merge multiple alpha-blended textures into a single baked texture for vegetation assets.

The following test object has subdivided planes, each with the texture of a single leaf. Opaque pixels use Diffuse BSDF and transparent pixels use Transparent BSDF. When rendered using an orthographic camera, the result is correct:

[image: rendered image]

However, when I attempt to bake a diffuse map, the texture is rendered at full opacity:

[image]

This prevents me from baking images for AO or tangent normal maps. Is there any way I can fix this?

This behaviour occurs on both Cycles or Blender Internal, and a solution for either would be useful.